# Google Maps API v3 and Overlay Map Types - tiles error when using fitBounds

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webkit

I have encountered a strange issue with the Google Maps Javascript API. When using the method fitBounds(), webkit browsers are animating the pan and zoom when zooming between certain zoom levels. This is nice, but when using an "Overlay Map Type", the original map tiles aren't displayed sometimes. I haven't been able to recreate this on smaller monitors, so I think it is related to large map canvases.

I have made a simple example page which is pretty much copied from the API documentation. In order to recreate the problem:

1) Open http://pastehtml.com/view/cqloxyo5v.html in Chrome (on either Mac or Windows) with a large monitor and make sure the window is maximized. I am using 24".

2) Press the "Click me!" button in the bottom left corner which triggers the fitBounds()-method with two coordinates that are outside the map scope.

3) The map will animate to fit the coordinates and some map tiles will become empty. If there was no animation, your browser window was probably too small. If it did animate but the tiles look ok, update the page and try it a few times again. It seems to happen sporadically.

This is what it looks like for me: https://vimeo.com/58366640

Has someone encountered something similar? Is there any way to disable the animation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: +1 for providing a video, wouldn't be possible for me to determine the issue without that

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, there are a lot of requests to give an option to disable the animation.

I didn't notice the behaviour as shown in the video, but for me the zooming-animation is a very unsightly process when switching between very high and very low zoom-levels.

I don't know if it would be an option in your case and if it will fix the issue, but I've found a possible workaround in OpenLayers, where it's possible to avoid the animation in Google Maps. They simply hide the complete map-container and show the container when the process has been finished.

In your case this would be:

```
  $().ready(function() {
      $("#clickButton").click(function() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(49.0, 2.55));
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(35.55, 139.78));
        var mapDiv=map.getDiv();
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'tilesloaded',
                                          function(){mapDiv.style.visibility=''});
        mapDiv.style.visibility="hidden";
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another repro link: http://tinyurl.com/baqvppr

It seems to be a Chrome bug. For some reason Chrome is running out of GPU memory.
You can vote for this issue here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175549

[image]

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the next Chrome release.

Answer (score 0):

By happenstance I needed to slightly pan my map to have all the markers show up. Besides fixing that problem, the map stopped animating on the various zooms. The effect is not exactly what one might want (the map goes blank, then the markers zoom to their spots, then the map with its new extents shows up), but it's better for what I need, and maybe it's better for you.  Here's the bottom of my function that puts markers on the map:

```
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
//This minimum zoom trick I got from StackOverflow:
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event){
    if (this.getZoom() >= 5){  
        this.setZoom(5) 
        }
    }); 
map.panBy(1,0);
```